# Get active directory picture using c++ code

Tags: c++, server, active-directory, ldap

I am working on a java web application with active directory using JNI interface.
i want to get the active directory users picture and found that the picture is stored as a octet string . I used IADsUser to get the value of the picture but i cant find any documentation or code how to use that value. I want to send this data through jni to java where i can render the picture.
Code i used to get the picture.

```
HRESULT GetUserObject()
{
    IADsUser* pUser;
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    CComBSTR  path = L"LDAP://WIN-F94H2MP3UJR.Test.local/CN=SomeOne";
    path += L",CN=Users,DC=Test,DC=local";
    HRESULT hr = ADsOpenObject(path, L"Administrator", L"pass@12",
        ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION, // For secure authentication
        IID_IADsUser,
        (void**)&pUser);
    if (FAILED(hr)) { return NULL; }
    VARIANT var;
    hr = pUser->get_Picture((VARIANT*)&var);
    std::string message = std::system_category().message(hr);
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
    return hr;
}
```

Microsoft documentation i used to code this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/iadsuser-property-methods). In this documentation they specified Get picture method which is what am looking for. Here as the hr prints operation completed successfully .  Help me how to work with this value or atleast help  me to print the value stored in var in c++. Thank you.

Comment: The value is the raw data of the image. You likely just need to [convert it to a plain byte array](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+convert+variant+to+byte+array) (since that's what it is) before you can use it (either write it to a file, or send the byte array to your Java app).

Comment: Yeah i want to send the byte array to the java first i need to convert any idea how to do so? i googled and found some post to but nothing makes sense

Comment: I've only done very little C++ coding, but this thread might help you understand the `VARIANT` type and how to get the actual data out of it: https://microsoft.public.vc.atl.narkive.com/KlnLjg7y/help-on-variant-vt-vartype I think the first step is to check the value of the `vt` property to see what the actual type of the data is.

Answer (score 0):

I had an old C++ project where I was already getting data from AD, so I decided to try this out. This is what I came up with to get the data into a byte array and write it to a file:

```
VariantInit(&var);
LONG lBound = 0;
LONG uBound = 0;

if (FAILED(pUser->get_Picture(&var)) ||
    FAILED(SafeArrayLock(var.parray)) ||
    FAILED(SafeArrayGetLBound(var.parray, 1, &lBound)) ||
    FAILED(SafeArrayGetUBound(var.parray, 1, &uBound))) {
    //handle failure
}

if (var.vt != VT_EMPTY) {
    const char* pData = static_cast<const char*>(var.parray->pvData);

    std::ofstream file("picture.jpg", std::ios::binary);
    file.write(pData, uBound);
    file.close();

    SafeArrayUnlock(var.parray);
}
VariantClear(&var);
```

The `vt` property will be `VT_EMPTY` if there is no picture, and `VT_ARRAY | VT_UI1` if it does. The data is a [`SAFEARRAY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-safearray). You need to use
[`SafeArrayGetLBound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-safearraygetlbound) and [`SafeArrayGetUBound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-safearraygetubound) to get the lower bound (probably always `0`) and the upper bound (length).

Comment: I just now saw your other question showing that you already figured this out :)